# Azure Data Lake Store access failure: Response status code indicates server error: 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: azure-data-lake

I am trying to download a file from data lake store, here is the code I used:

```
    _adlsAccountName = "myadls";
    _resourceGroupName = "NavigationResource";
    _location = "East US 2";
    _subId = "myid";
    string localFolderPath = @"E:\temp\"; 
    string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localFolderPath, "modGR_vrt.tsv");
    string remoteFolderPath = "/Rnds/";
    string remoteFilePath = Path.Combine(remoteFolderPath, "modGR_vrt.tsv");

    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
    var domain = "microsoft.com"; // any value
    var clientId = "my client id"; // this is a native app
    var clientSecret = "clientSecret"; 
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(domain, clientCredential).Result;

    _adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds); 

    var result = _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.GetFileStatus(_adlsAccountName, srcPath);
```

I am getting this exception: 
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.TransientFaultHandling.HttpRequestWithStatusException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Response status code indicates server error: 403 (Forbidden).

I have assigned my app read/write/execute access on Rnds folder and all its files. did I miss anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the permissions on the Rnds folder and files, you also need Execute (X) permission on all the ancestors of Rnds.

See *Permissions needed to read a file* in this document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control